# Can't get angularjs to initialize

Tags: angularjs

Sorry if this isn't a particulary enlightening question, but I am at a loss as to why I can't get angularjs to run on my page.

I've stripped it down to the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Inigo/CvWE5/1/

Here is my code:

```
    var app = angular.module('iwd-cms', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider',
      function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
            controller: 'TourManager'
          }).
          otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
          });
      }]);


    app.controller('TourManager', function($scope){
        alert('hello world');       
    });
```

Comment: Mind posting your HTML as well?

Comment: You apparently do not use any html -- put `ng-app="iwd-cms"` to automatically bootstrap the application.

Comment: Hi artur, as far as I understand, jsFiddle adds the html and body tags for you. If you look under 'Fiddle options', you'll see I've already added ng-app="iwd-cms" to the body tag.

Comment: Add a div and set the ng-controller to TourManager. You'll get your alert box to show.

Comment: Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CvWE5/5/ You are right you provided `ng-app`

Comment: Ah, thanks, Artur. So (as I say below), the problem is that I didn't provide a template for the route, and this is mandatory? You can't  provide only a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As according to an issue on AngularJS's github repo, you must include a template to match up with your controller:

```
$routeProvider.
      when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'TourManager.html',
        controller: 'TourManager'
      }).
```

See issue 1838 issue on their github repo: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1838

It seems to be an ongoing issue; please look for alternative code solutions at the Url.

Comment: Ah, so if I undersand, the answer is that the *when()* clause HAS to give a templateUrl? You can't just give a controller?

Comment: Actually, I don't know about that. Let me experiment on a JSfiddle

Comment: OK, Thank you. I think that's the crux of it. (If you find that's true, then if you edit your answer to state it - templates are mandatory when declaring routes - then I'll accept. Cheers).

Comment: I realized that I need to understand what you want: are you trying to switch controllers using ng-view?

Comment: Well, my intent was to have two (or more) different routes, each with its own controller, but *not* necessarily loading different templates. I think I'm beginning to realise that this is not using angular in the way it was intended.. However, I'd still like to know if declaring a template - as in your code above - is mandatory?

Comment: The url is informative: at the moment you must include a template

Comment: So my original question wasn't so stupid after all, it seems ;) Thanks for your help!